# jQuery simultaneous Animation not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have an HTML page with two `div` elements. One is red and the other is blue. The red one is in the top left corner while the blue one is on the top right. I have a "click me" link, which when clicked, should animate. Both the boxes should move down. It is not happening. Can someone tell me why?

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #box{
            background:red;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }
        #box1{
            background: blue;
            width: 300px;
            height:300px;
            float: right;
            position: relative;
        }

        a{
            position:absolute;
            top: 310px;
            left: 550px;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('a').click(function(){
                $('#box').animate(function(){bottom : "0px";}, 2000);
                $('#box1').animate(function(){bottom : "0px";}, 2000);
                })
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box" ></div>
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <br>
    <a href="#">Click Me!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try animating them both at the same time:

```
    $(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
            $('#box, #box1').animate({top: "300px"}, 2000);
        });
    });
```

Also your `bottom: 0px` does nothing when there is not size to the `<body>`

I changed it to move the height of the box.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/fjVpZ/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('#box').animate({bottom : 0}, 2000);
  $('#box1').animate({bottom : 0}, 2000);
})
```

Try that. There were a few syntax errors in your code.

Comment: @Neal, please explain.  His [jsFiddle is working](http://jsfiddle.net/v8hdZ/) after all.

Answer (score 0):

```
​  $(function(){
     $('a').click(function(){     
         $('#box,#box1').animate({top:"100%"}, 2000);
    }); 
});
```

css (absolute in place of relative)

```
#box{
        background:red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 300px;

        position: absolute;
        top:0;
    left:0;
    }
    #box1{
        background: blue;
        width: 100px;
        height:300px;

        position: absolute;
    top: 0;right:0;
    }

    a{
        position:absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 550px;
    }​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. I think you meant this.

```
function(){
    return { bottom: "0px" };
}
```

not

```
function(){
    bottom: "0px";
}
```

So here's a quick fix.
Change this

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('#box').animate(function(){bottom : "0px";}, 2000);
        $('#box1').animate(function(){bottom : "0px";}, 2000);
    });
});
```

To:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('#box, #box1').animate( {bottom : "0px" }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Also you need a defined height for document.body so the items can move.

`.animate()` api : http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
.animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )
```

properies are objects literals, not functions.
Example:

```
{ body: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #box{
            background:red;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            float: left;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #box1{
            background: blue;
            width: 300px;
            height:300px;
            float: right;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
        }

        a{
            position:absolute;
            top: 310px;
            left: 550px;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('a').click(function(){
                $('#box').animate({bottom : 0}, 2000);
                $('#box1').animate({bottom : 0}, 2000);
                })
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box" ></div>
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <br>
    <a href="#">Click Me!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

On JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xkizer/yym6s/

Comment: Note the changes to the animate method. {bottom : 0} instead of function(){...}, and the change to CSS. Using absolute positioning instead of relative positioning. You can also combine the two animations as @Neal suggested, doing $('#box1, #box2').animate({bottom : 0}, 2000);